# psql cannot display german "Umlaute"

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

I am using psql and realized that the German letters ä, ö, ü are not displayed correctly. For example, ö is displayed as õ. ü is displayed as a three in the exponent...

```
WARNING: Console code page (850) differs from Windows code page 
(1252) 8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql 
reference page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
```

How can I change that?

OS: Windows 10
psql 13.3

The table I have imported to postgres is encoded in UTF8.

I am new to postgres and psql, so sorry for the dumb question.

[image]

[image]

In the second print screen one can see that the character 'ü' in 'Eigentümer', 'Zürich' and 'Graubünden' is displayed incorrectly.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? This is typically a problem of the console which runs psql, not psql itself

Comment: In `psql` what does `\l` show as the encoding, collate and ctype for the database?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks, I have posted a screenshot of my database. Encoding is UTF8, ctype is German_Switzerland.1252 and collate also German_Switzerland.1252.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: I have searched the web for hours but couldn't find a satisfying answer. Some say  to use a chcp 1252 command on the command line but this is not a persistent solution. The difference between the console code page and the Windows code page still differs and lead to character display errors when starting a new psql window.

Comment: have you tried:

       SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';

Comment: @user939857 yes, I have, but this was not good. My password for postgres broke and I couldn't log in anymore. I had to re-install postgres again.

Comment: Try to use ascii-only characters for passwords. And table names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From the command line or the Terminal:

   chcp 1252
2. open psql

   psql -U postgres
3. set client_encoding:

   SET client_encoding='WIN1252'
4. import file:

   \i Path/to/your/.sqlFile

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; just use

> \encoding 'UTF8'

Comment: You mean before importing a table? Or everytime you start postgres?

Comment: @aurumpurum you need to clarify it every time you conect to your db